# Getting a value out of Textbox

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I know its stupid asking this question but i cant seems to extra Value(int) out of my textbox for Windows 8 Metro application. Have been trying for hours , feel so dumb , someone help me out . Thanks

```
int test = textboxSharedTotal.GetValue;
int test = int.Parse(textboxSharedTotal);
int test = int.Parse(textboxSharedTotal.Text);
```

Comment: could you give little more details and code that you tried?

Comment: I think you didnt set anything in your textbox hence no value. Check bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int test = int.Parse(textboxSharedTotal.Text);

should work. without more details it is difficult to help you.  If this textbox appears in a dialog box but you want to extract the value and reference it in the main form/application you will need to declare int test outside of the dialog box function call and pass it in as a ref string. then you can set it = int.Parse(textboxSharedTotal.Text); and still have the value after the user closes the dialog box.

without more details i have no idea if that is your problem though.

Comment: err i meant pass it in as a ref int not ref string